# Take Pity On My Poor Soul

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was someone out there that would take pity on my poor soul? I have a piece of JavaScript that is trying its level best to put me into an early grave. I am very new to all of this and would be eternally greatful if someone could see thier way to helping me before I lose the will to live.

I have to add the following two groups, occasion and name of sender, to the piece of JavaScript below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>(ii)</title)

var recipient
// Declare other variables here

recipient =
    window.prompt ('Please enter the name of the recipient', '');
// prompt for other values here

// output the customised greeting here

</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't know if it's the markup, but this doesn't look valid.  I don't see an opening tag for <script>

Comment: Don't lose your will to live over this. And give your question a proper title.

Comment: A full description of what you are actually trying to do might help.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking for.  It sounds like you just want someone to add two more variables and input prompts to this code.  That's pretty straightforward, just following the pattern of the code you already have.  Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: You're missing opening script tag, and your closing title tag has a typo. Maybe fix those first and give the JS code another shot.

Comment: You should post what you've already tried and why it's not working.  Also, this looks a lot like a homework question.

Comment: keparo, I'm tempted to roll back you edit, as I'm sure it's not at all what the OP intended.

Comment: @jason - I did. Not sure why keparo edited it the way he did, but it's not what the OP had originally posted

Comment: I'm going to vote to reopen this. Despite the bizarre manner of asking, there's still a quite valid question in there, in my opinion.

Comment: @paxdiablo: a homework question, though. just like wyzard says "It sounds like you just want someone to add two more variables and input prompts to this code. That's pretty straightforward, just following the pattern of the code you already have".

Comment: @Thilo, if it's a homework question, that's reason for guiding the OP rather than giving a direct answer. But I still don't believe it's a reason to close. I also like to clarify whether it's homework with the OP since there's ample precedent of people self-educating here with questions that look like homework, but that's a different issue. Still, I've voted to reopen, others may not agree but, in the end, the swarm that is SO (of which I am one small part) will be right :-)

Answer (score 6):

I'm no web genius, nor am I the religious type who can help you with this "soul" business, but it seems to me you are missing the opening `<script>` tag.

Also, the closing `</title>` should end with `>` and not `)`.

**Update**: looking at the edit history, it looks like the missing and malformed tags were introduced by another SO reader who was editing your question.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @asveikau Nah, the malformed tags were there in the first version of the post, or that's at least how I read the edit history anyways

Comment: Ok guys basically what it is to do with is this. Its a part of a program that would let the user and their own 'personal touches' to a greeting card message of their choice.

I obviously made a mistake typing as far as the title are concerned so I can see what Ive done there. The other two lines that need to go in are to do with occasion and the other is the senders details.

I must apologise for the slight confusion on this.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

- The `<title>` tag isn't closed.
- The `<script>` tag isn't opened.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to get all those fields into JavaScript pop-ups. Even if you could, you would run into trouble when you try and send some sort of message using JavaScript (that's what it looks like you're trying to do, any way).

If you write an HTML form and have it post to a server that uses something like PHP or Servlets, you might have better luck.